# GCC and clang: subexpression not valid in a constant expression

Tags: gcc, clang, c++14, constexpr

Consider the following code:

```
template<int... V>
static constexpr int f(int v) {
    int a[] = { (v ^= V, 0)... };       // Line 3
    return v;
}

static constexpr int i = f<0x00>(0x11); // Line 7

int main() { }
```

It compiles with GCC and fails to compile with clang with the following error:

> main.cpp:7:22: error: constexpr variable 'i' must be initialized by a constant expression
>
> [...]
>
> main.cpp:3:23: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression

Note that it doesn't depend on the fact that I'm using a template function.
In other terms, neither the code above nor the one below compile with clang:

```
static constexpr int mix(int v, int u) {
    int a[] = { (v ^= u, 0) };
    return v;
}

static constexpr int mf = mix(0x11, 0x00);

int main() { }
```

Which compiler is right?

Comment: C++17 says: `return (v ^ ... ^ V);` :-)

Comment: I'd think this might be because ^= assigns a value to v. But then again, this could be resolved at compile time.

Comment: @Columbo _C++14_, compiled with `-std=c++14`. There is also the flag _c++14_ to the question.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know, but I can't use it yet on this project... :-(

Comment: @KlemensMorgenstern: Assignment is definitely allowed in constexpr functions (since C++14). This really should work.

Comment: Strange. Btw: I don't think (not sure for initializaion) you have a guarantee for the order of evaluation in this exmample. So this might be broken on that level already. Why don't you use a recursive solution?

`static constexpr int f_impl(int val, int first){return val ^ first;}`

`template<typename ...Args> static constexpr int f_impl(int val, int first, Args...args) {return f_impl(val ^ first, args...);} `

`template<int... V> static constexpr int f(int v) { return f_impl(v, V...);}`

Comment: @KlemensMorgenstern Find an alternative solution is not the purpose of the question. :-)

Comment: @skypjack That's why I've written it into the comments, not as an answer ;).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb It fails also if you use `+=` and `0x00` as values...

Comment: @skypjack i noticed.. flawed thinking. However, it compiles if you remove the comma operator. Just saying `int a[] = { (v ^= V)... };` works.

Comment: Weird.. this compiles again `int a[] = { (+(v ^= V), 0)... };` seems like if it's doing an lvalue to rvalue conversion after the assignment, then it works.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Wow, I didn't notice it (well, actually that's why I consider you far more skilled than me). I've opened a bug to clang, maybe it's worth to add there those details. I'm not at the laptop, in a couple of hours I'll be able to get the link to the bug back. Sorry.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-libt Question updated, I've added the link to the issue opened to clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27989), it is a bug of clang:

> the bug is something odd about the left-hand side of a comma operator

Confirmed and fixed.